# How can I monitor my Remote-Git-Repo for commits/pushs, to then copy/paste the files into a specific folder

Tags: java, git, spring-boot, maven, gitlab

I hope that someone can help me with my problem. I am quite new to stuff like Git, Spring Boot and in general Java (Maven Projects). But i want to try to modernize our archiving system for our PL/SQL scripts. Right now, we archive them by hand and zip a version with the old date to then reserv it, that no other developer can make changes at the same time. After finishing working on the script, the developer releases the script in a specific folder (release) where it gets tested. After a successful test, other developer can now finally work on the script again.

Now, i wanna try and modernize this whole procedure:

1. I wanna import all our PL/SQL scripts into GitLab
2. If some developer is working on a script and commits/pushes it, i want that a action happens, where the script gets also copied into our release-directory, where it can be tested from our consultant (in context of the specific ticket the script gets released to)
3. I dont excactly know if my thought fits in here but i think it would fit the modernizing concept, if a new branch would be used for this (developer/testing branch). So that after a period of 2 weeks (our scrum sprint) all changes could get merged into the master branch

I would like to know, what is the best way to realize this and how would i go forward. Because i dont know if my idea with GitLab + Spring Boot Application is the best in this scenario and even if it is, how do i manage to monitor that. Its the starting point that i am missing. Once its there i think i can handle everything but the beginning is my problem (and missing examples).

I am sorry in advance for my bad english and hope you can help me getting started with my idea :)

Thx
Steven

Comment: Welcome! Monitoring a project is normally done through a hook. There are different events that you can... _attach to_. You can also use things like jenkins to take care of _other stuff_ after something is pushed into a branch.

Comment: @eftshift0 Thanks for your quick reply. I saw/read something about Webhook in this context but wasnt sure if it fits my needs. But i will take a deeper look into that and Jenkins too. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: It is Git-Hooks, not Webhooks: https://githooks.com/

Comment: @ppuschmann Thank you too. I will take a look at it right now ;)

Comment: Have a look at [git-flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow): „_A collection of Git extensions to provide high-level repository operations_“.